# What power supply for servo?

Tags: arduino, requirements, servo

This might be a stupid question although I tried to search everywhere and the answer is kinda of fuzzy.
I am trying to power a MG996R High Torque Metal Gear Dual Ball Bearing Servo (manual and description below). This is attached to an arm (wooden) that should with right friction spin a dish (Monitor holder). This is all powered by the arduino.
The problem is that the specific voltage as in the manual says is 6v(current 500mA to 900 mA) but the operating voltage is `4.2V a 7.2V` exactly how written and it's confusing.

I am planning on hooking it up to a Arduino UNO R3 ATmega 328.
I though about buying a hook up of 4 AA batteries 1.5V and make up to 6V to power the servo but I don't know if it will be powering it for much.
The other option is to buy a 7.2V power supply or a LiPo to power it but so confusing.
Here is a link to the manual from the manufacturer:

[Manual](http://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/MG996R_Tower-Pro.pdf)

Thank you all!

Comment: Seriously?! Down vote?!?!?!?!?!? Come on!! At least drop a comment why you are down voting!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A 6v supply for the servo will be fine, just make it separate from the supply used by the Arduino. You will need a ground reference wire between the two supplies.

This servo has a stall current of @2.5a if I remember right. You can get close to that under a heavy load, with typical use being @1a or less, but it's based on your load.

I would also go for a 6v NiMH battery pack to save on replacing 1.5v alkaline batteries.

Comment: Thank you I also noticed that it works if I attach ground with ground of the micro-controller instead of ground of the actual power supply. 6V 2.6 A worked